A word for an academic underachiever at highschool
There is a valedictorian, straight-A student, the top of one's class, but what do you call a student who is living just comfortable with their Cs? Also, I'm curious if there are any terms for students scoring Bs or Fs on average.

I think the answer is in your title, an underachiever "someone who is less successful than they should be at school or at work"

A student capable of A work but getting Bs and Cs is said to be "coasting" in American English.  Could be the same term is used in the UK. Don't know, and I'm too lazy to find out.
coasting is riding a bicycle without pedaling, relying upon momentum or, better yet, gravity.

Coasting also used in UK.  I could add this as an answer, but "under the radar" is also used as a metaphor  (someone doing badly, but not so badly that they get noticed by the teacher)

Can we call a person that is coasting 'a coaster'? I'm looking for nouns specifically to name a person with a typical academic performance. Are there any other nouns to describe an F-student? Is it a straight-F student? Can I use this naming convention to go with A through F?

Yes, you could say the person who is intentionally doing no more than they need to do in order to "get by" is a coaster.   That is is the essential feature.  But a person with learning issues who is getting D's and F's is not a coaster.  If you are a star striker but decide not to use all your speed in a game but to "take it easy", you are "coasting".
